# Why does the back button close apps instead actions back in Webview?(react native)

Tags: android, react-native

i add this code im my MainActivity.java but nothing happens.
I use android emulator

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

it`s my MainActivity.java

```
package com.mobile;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

import expo.modules.splashscreen.singletons.SplashScreen;
import expo.modules.splashscreen.SplashScreenImageResizeMode;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    // SplashScreen.show(...) has to be called after super.onCreate(...)
    // Below line is handled by '@expo/configure-splash-screen' command and it's discouraged to modify it manually
    SplashScreen.show(this, SplashScreenImageResizeMode.CONTAIN, ReactRootView.class, false);
  }


    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "main";
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
                return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could fix it using fragments.

You have to create a fragment(exampleFragment.kt & fragment_example.xml) with the view and associate it to the activity.
And them, in your activity add de manager:
 `supportFragmentManager .beginTransaction() .replace(R.id.---Fragment, ---Fragment()) .addToBackStack(null) .commit()`

"addToBackStack(null)" is what makes the window go back

The official page explains the fragments.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl